# Having trouble designing the database relationship for Comments & Critic in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

I'm still learning how to design databases for my applications and need some help organizing the database for a Movie Critic application.

A critic has many comments and a comment can only belong to one critic. Do I need a link table?

My understanding is the following:

**Comment Table**

- id
- comment
- critic_id

**Critic Table**

- id
- first_name
- last_name

I understand how to link the Comment to the critic through the critic_id. However, a critic can have multiple comments and I'm confused as how to design this into the database. Obviously a Critic cannot have multiple Comments in the same database row so my assumption is that I need some sort of link table.

I'm using rails and could really benefit from details on how to properly set up the relationships in the model (ex: has_many, belongs_to, etc.)

Comment: Read the Rails Guide on [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). It will answer your question in its entirety and leave you with a much better understanding of the concepts involved. (And when you're done read the rest of the Rails Guides; they're superb.)

Comment: Awesome, I'm going to read through it now. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, it was a simple has_many & belongs_to. I guess I was over thinking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a one-to-many relationship, your design is fine. Multiple comments of the same critic will have multiple rows in `Comment` table, each with its own `id` but sharing the same `critic_id`.

You only need to consider whether to keep the non-identifying relationship that you have now or perhaps use an [identifying](http://www.gc.maricopa.edu/business/sylvester/cis164/er2b.htm) relationship instead.

Only if you had a many-to-many relationship would you need a link (aka. junction) table.